# Como melhorar a visualização de arquivos de logs?

Tags: linux, log

Eu estou tentando analisar alguns arquivos de logs gerados no Linux e tenho notado que é muito chato de entender onde uma linha está começando/terminando.

Gostaria de saber se existe algum tipo de comando ou ferramentas para melhor visualização de logs.

Exemplo de log chato gerado pelo Mysql, visto na linha de comando:

[image: Horrível ver esse log no linux]

Alguém sabe informar alguma ferramenta pra melhor visualização/monitoramento de logs?

Answer (score 2):

Realmente analisar logs é uma tarefa muito chata, mas dependendo do contexto voce pode usar algumas ferramentas tais como o pipe (`|`) seguido de `grep`, por exemplo, digamos que vc queira "inspecionar" syslog em busca de eventos gerados pela applicação kdeconnect, então iria no diretorio de logs e:

```
$ tail -n 30 syslog | grep kdeconnect

Jun 20 16:23:22 sidon-pc-linux org.kde.kdeconnect[1986]: kdeconnect.plugin.battery: Deleting stale BatteryDbusInterface for "Asus ZenFone 5"
Jun 20 16:23:22 sidon-pc-linux org.kde.kdeconnect[1986]: kdeconnect.plugin.sftp: add to dolphin
....
```

### [Multitail:](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/examples.php)

Se gosta de algo mais voltado para GUI, pode usar o multital. Veja os [screenshots.](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/screenshots.php)

[image: Multital]

### [Glogg:](http://glogg.bonnefon.org/index.html)

Outra boa opção (para usuarios ubuntu, já está nos repositórios), é o glogg, [veja os screens.](http://glogg.bonnefon.org/screenshots.html)

[image: glogg screens]